# How to achieve LDAP authentication in Django, How to access User object in View?

Tags: django, ldap

I want to build a site using Django wherein to enter it, the users have to authenticate themselves through LDAP server.
I have read the python-ldap configuration and configured settings.py accordingly. I'm able to authenticate a user from local database, but when I try to do it through LDAP, it doesn't work.

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')]

import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, GroupOfNamesType

# Baseline configuration.
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://10.1.10.10"

AUTH_LDAP_CONNECTION_OPTIONS = {
            ldap.OPT_REFERRALS: 0
} 

AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "cn=myname,dc=example,dc=com"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "dontevenask"

AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=users,dc=example,dc=com",
                                       ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)")

#AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE = "uid=%(user)s,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com"

AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
            "first_name": "givenName",
  "last_name": "sn",
            "email": "mail"
}


AUTH_LDAP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER = True
AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUP_PERMS = True

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
            'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
            'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '^eh5xdkui7vw!^x&l%q44ak6+yglnx5q(tqwd8l+w!sxml7q!&'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'my_app',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'users.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'users.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS':{
                'read_default_file':'/home/user/config.cnf',
                 },
    }

}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Here is my views.py file

```
  def loggedin(request):
        uid = request.user.username
        return render_to_response('loggedin.html',
                                  {'full_name':uid})
```

And the loggedin.html file

```
{% block content %}

        <h2> Hi {{full_name}} Logged in! </h2>
        <p> Click <a href="/accounts/logout/"> here </a> to logout </p>
{% endblock %}
```

I did refer to other posts but didn't find the solution.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here goes the answer!

I changed `"(uid=%(user)s)")` to `"(samaccountname=%(user)s)")` which did the trick.

Having the logger helped locate what the problem was - was it even talking to LDAP or just trying to authenticate with the local database.

Comment: Good yo hear you got it working! I see you are using AD, as am i. I had to make my own backend since the standard django-ldap backend did not provide any SASL support -- it was sending the password PLAIN TEXT over the network, since the AD server did not have TLS support enabled. I have the solution online https://github.com/susundberg/django-auth-ldap-ad

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues that might cause the LDAP authentication not to work.

I am assuming you are running linux host. Have you verified that the LDAP settings you have entered works properly? Use command line tool 'ldapsearch' verify that the server works and responses as you might expect.

After you have successfully authenticated with ldapsearch and the authentication is still not working in Django i suggest you put [logging on](https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/logging.html) on and paste the logs somewhere.

Without futher info its hard to say what part of your setup is incorrect.

Comment: Well, I used logger and tried to zero in on what was causing the error. My logger says 'Caught LDAPError while authenticating user_name: INVALID_CREDENTIALS({'info': '80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903C5, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v23f0', 'desc': 'Invalid credentials'},)

Although the credentials are correct. I guess there's something wrong in settings.py. Any more inputs?

Comment: Well the server says that the credentials that you gave are invalid, or some other setting is wrong. Were you able to do the bind with the 'ldapsearch' tool? I think django tries to first do login/bind with the credentials you have inputted when doing the POST at the login, those are correct too ? Verify with ldapsearch!

Comment: Yes, I was able to connect to ldap from the command line, but wasn't working with django. It was a settings.py issue. Thanks, the logging helped me locate the problem.